# Sync clipboard with a file with shell script

Tags: linux, sh

I'm trying to make a shell script that syncs a file and system clipboard using xclip, or any other method that may be possible.

For example, if `clipboard.txt` contains **"hello world"**, it'll copy over to the system clipboard. If a new item is added to the system clipboard, it should replace the contents of `clipboard.txt`

If I were to copy the contents from `clipboard.txt` every so often, how would I make it so that it doesn't overwrite the system clipboard if there is a new item added to it?

Here's what I use to copy one way from the file: `while true; do xclip -sel clip clipboard; sleep 2; done`

Comment: soooo you want to _get_ the clipboard? See `xclip -o > clipboard.txt`?

Comment: Trying to get it to run continuously, but without having one overwriting another (clipboard and file)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [clipnotify](https://github.com/cdown/clipnotify) to go from the clipboard to a file. It lets you create an event listener that triggers whenever the clipboard changes, at which point you could write to the target file.

```sh
# clipnotify exits after every clipboard event
while clipnotify; do
    # save clipboard to file whenever it changes
    xclip -o > clipboard.txt
done
```